# angular 2 accessing data from input cell in a *ngFor loop

Tags: angular

```
<table class="border-grey ocj-admin-table">
    <tr>
        <th>Customer ID</th>
        <th>Contract ID</th>
        <th>Product Instance ID</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let journeyDetail of journeyDetails; let i = index">
        <td ><input #custId type ="textField"/></td>
        <td ><input #contractId_{{i}} type ="textField"/></td>
        <td ><a  href="?{{custId_{{i}}.value}}&{{contractId_{{i}}.value}}">launch</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to launch to the url which is made from input fields. But I am getting an error with the two curly brackets in the href.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is e.g. `custId_0.value`? Could you show a [mcve]? Why put such complicated stuff in the template rather than the objects you're displaying?

Answer (score 0):

Nesting curly braces is invalid

Just use

```
{{custId + '_' + i + '.' + value}}
```

You also can't have template variable names built dynamically

```
 #contractId_{{i}}
```

is invalid

The `{{i}}` part isn't necessary anyway.

All the elements in `*ngFor` can have the same template variable. If you refer to one the closest is used.